# Format of code for classification with randomForest

Tags: r, random-forest

In two online courses they wrote the code like:

```
randomForest(x = response, y = independent)
```

But I would prefer to do the folllowing:

```
randomForest(response ~ ., data = data.frame)
```

Is there any difference? I get the same result either way, but just wanted to check I'm not learning something the wrong way.

Comment: Formula syntax in R is generally `y ~ x`.  The dot placeholder means "all other variables in `data` other than `y`".  So `y ~ ., data=df` is the same as `y=df$y, x=df[which(names(df)!="y")]`.  My point is: they are the same when `x` is "all of `df` except for `y`".

Comment: Awesome, all I needed to know. Cheers!

Comment: For randomForest using `randomForest(x = response, y = independent)` is faster than using the formula interface. The formula interface, creates a full copy of your data and does some other stuff before calling the default randomforest call with the x, y interface. The same goes for a lot of other packages.

Comment: @phiver didn't know that, thanks for the tip! (sorry for the late reply as well).